# For each object in array, how to resolve promises that retrieve DB data and populate dropdown in sequential order?

Tags: javascript, promise, arrow-functions, sequential

I have an array of objects called `projects`. Each project has a `project_id`. I need to retrieve all members assigned to a project from the DB using the `project_id`, check if each member is approved, and then populate a dropdown select with the project titles.

Since I need to wait for the GET request to complete before the other tasks, I wrapped the request in a promise. Unfortunately, I can't use `async await` because our team uses promises as the standard. For each `project` object in the array, I need to execute this promise and chain it with `.then()` to check the approval statuses and fill the dropdown.

This is what I have so far:

```
var select = document.getElementById('projectSelect')

projectArray.map(project => () => {        // map each project in array to a new promise
    getMembers(project.project_id)
        .then(members => {                 // pass in array of member objects returned from getMembers()
            if (members.every(member => member.approved)) {

                // populate dropdown with projects
                let option = document.createElement("option")
                option.text = project.title
                option.value = project.project_id
                select.appendChild(option)
            }
        }
})

function getMembers(project_id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../../../getMembers",
                data: { 
                    "project_id": project_id
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    return resolve(data)
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    return reject(error)
                }
            })
    }
}
```

The functions inside the `.map()` are not run so I'm not sure if I have to call them again. How do I run this promise and the following function in order? I want to complete those steps for the first project, before moving to the next project. I would appreciate any suggestions, thanks!

Comment: `The functions inside the .map() are not run` why not? what is the length of `projectArray` just before you try to use `.map`

Comment: `Unfortunately, I can't use async await because our team uses promises as the standard` ... async/await is 100% made for using Promises

Comment: what are you using to `// send AJAX GET request`

Comment: `// map each project in array to a new promise` but you're actually doing `// map each project in array to undefined` because you don't return anything directly in the callback code

Comment: Having said all that - the first problem is why `The functions inside the .map() are not run` - that's your first issue to solve

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. You're mapping to an array of functions that are never executed. Instead of `project => () =>`, it should just be `(project) =>`

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry for the late reply, I'll get back to you by today or tomorrow. Thank you for the replies, and I will let you know why the functions are not running and what errors I am seeing.

I understand async/await is used in Promises, I just can't use the `async` and `await` keywords since my team has used Promises throughout our JS file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Promise.all` instead of waiting for each promise to get resolved is a better approach. Here's my solution:

```
const promises = projectArray.map(project => getMembers(project.project_id));

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(arrayOfMembersArrays => {
        // arrayOfMembersArrays is an array of arrays, where each inner array contains members for a specific project

        if (arrayOfMembersArrays.every(members => members.every(member => member.approved))) {
            // Populate dropdown with projects
        }
    })

function getMembers(project_id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // TODO: Add AJAX GET request
        
        // Resolve with result
        resolve(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried using Promise.all but that just runs all the promises concurrently and I need them to resolve one by one. I need to get the data and populate the dropdown before moving to the next project. Promise.all doesn't help with that.